# Splash screen issue

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am creating a splash screen using the following code ,when i press back key the application moves to the home screen and within a few seconds shows my next mainmenu screen.I am calling finish() in onBackPressed(),I want to close the app on pressing back key in the splash screen.can any one help me on this??

Thanks!!

```
     Thread splashThread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           try {
              int waited = 0;
              while (_active && (waited < 2000)) {
                 sleep(100);
                 if(_active) {
                     waited += 100;
                 }
              }
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
              // do nothing
           } finally {

               finish();
               startActivity(new Intent("next activity"));
               stop();
           }
        }
     };
     splashThread.start();
```

Comment: This is mainly a guess, but what I think you ought to do is, stopping this `splashThread` once you receive `onBackPressed()`. Or at least tell it not to call `startActivity(Intent)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working in my application

```
public class Splash extends Activity {
protected boolean _active = true;
protected int _splashTime = 3000;
Thread splashTread;
private boolean stop = false;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    splashTread = new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                int waited = 0;
                while(_active && (waited < _splashTime)) {
                    sleep(100);
                    if(_active) {
                        waited += 100;
                    }
                }

            } catch(InterruptedException e) {
                // do nothing
            } finally {

                if(!stop){
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this,Home.class));
                    finish();
                }
                else
                    finish();
            }
        }

    };
    splashTread.start();

}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

        if(splashTread.isAlive())
            this.stop = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: This was helpful, but _active has no use. It is set to true, never set to false, and only used in conditional statements.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you call  `finish();` before the `startActivity(new Intent("next activity"));`

Swap `finish();` with `startActivity(new Intent("next activity"));`

Comment: Making such change should have no effect at all. `finish()` is called for _current_ Activity in any case.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Hero..i tried to swap finish(); with startActivity(new Intent("next activity")); ..but not working..

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
SplashScreen.this.finish();
```

where SplashScreen is the name of the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

this solution only solves the problem for the back-button. If users press the home-button the unwanted behavior will still occur. Wouldn't it be easier to overwrite the onStop method and do your thing in there?

```
@Override
public void onStop(){
    super.onStop();
    if(splashTread.isAlive())
       this.stop = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SplashActivity extends Activity {

    Handler handler;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

        handler=new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, Home.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        },3000);
    }
}
```

AndriodManifest.xml

```
    <activity
        android:name=".SplashActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```